# Doctrine migration with data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, data-migration

The [Doctrine migration documents](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.2/index.html) explain how to migrate the schema, however, are surprisingly silent on how to migrate the associated data.

For my migration, I am breaking a few tables into multiple tables and renaming a couple of tables.

How should data be moved during a migration?  Is the script I came up below a good approach or bad?

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
* Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
*/
final class Version20200525134530 extends AbstractMigration
{
    private $table1, $table2;

    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return 'Changing schema and data';
    }

    public function preUp(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        //If memory becomes an issue, write to a file
        $this->table1 = $this->getData('SELECT * FROM table1');
        $this->table2 = $this->getData('SELECT * FROM table2');
    }
    private function getData(string $sql):array
    {
        $stmt = $this->connection->query($sql);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();        
    }

    public function postUp(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // Manupulate data as necessary
        foreach($this->table1 as $table1) {
            $this->addSql('INSERT INTO newTable1 (id, x, y, z) VALUES (:id: :x, :y, :z)');
        }
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

        // Generated by Doctrine using: ./vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations diff
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE newTable1 (id INT NOT NULL, x INT, y INT, z INT, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE newTable2 (id INT NOT NULL, x INT, y INT, z INT, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE table1');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE table2');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

        // Generated by Doctrine using: ./vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations diff
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question indeed, I have done similar to you, just added the data to the migration file itself with either `addSql('INSERT...` or even used the entity manager inside the migration files to manipulate entities directly. Probably not best practise but gets the job done.

Comment: @Oli.  Thanks.  Ever need to get auto-incrementing keys?  Only way I could do it is directly using `$this->connection`, but they get executed before `addSql()` which makes it extra tricky.

Comment: No sorry, but you could try running your sql via the connection perhaps instead of `addSql()` and then get `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, that might work.

Comment: @Oli  Yes, that is exactly what I did and it worked as desired.  Dry runs didn't work but not a big deal.  Still surprising that I couldn't find more about this when searching.  Not sure, but think maybe I should be using fixtures. https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

Comment: Oh, if you are using it for development mock data there are certainly other options than migrations. I use data fixtures for development and I have tried github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures however I personally found it a bit cumbersome to have to mock data in each of my tests. I have my own fixture loader, https://github.com/oligus/doctrine-fixtures, that takes mysql xml dumps straight into the database and for testing I use Sqlite in memory db, superfast.

Comment: Note that you can't use `addSql()` in `postUp()` - it won't be executed. Also, if you make changes to the `$schema` object in `up($schema)` note that statements added in`up($schema)` using `$this->addSql()` will be executed before the `$schema` changes.